# Creating a new column with most frequent strings of an other column ignoring NA

Tags: r

I have the following database

```r
structure(list(source = c("NA", "NA", "OSM", "SIGE", "OSM", "OSM", 
NA, "SIGE"), longitude = c(20.5, 20.5, 
20.5, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 24.9), latitude = c(-4.2, 
-4.2, -4.2, -4.3,  -4.3,  -4.3,  -4.3, -5.9)), row.names = c(443593L, 260726L, 165397L, 
55084L, 426578L, 341763L, 440945L, 481831L), class = "data.frame")
```

I created a column in which I have the most numerous sources for longitude and latitude with the following function :

```r
library(data.table)
dataM<-setDT(data)[, .N, .(longitude, source)][order(N), .(first = first(source)),longitude]
```

Which gave me the following output :

```r
structure(list(longitude = c(20.5, 15.2, 24.9), first = c("NA", "OSM", "SIGE")), row.names = c(443593L, 260726L, 165397L), class = "data.frame")
```

However I would like to ignore missing values and obtain the following output :

```r
structure(list(longitude = c(20.5, 15.2, 24.9), first = c("OSM", "OSM", "SIGE")), row.names = c(443593L, 260726L, 165397L), class = "data.frame")
```

Do you have any idea of how can I obtain this output?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the data we have some values as string NA (`"NA"`) and some actual  `NA`. We can use `type.convert` to change the data to respective types and then use `na.omit` to drop `NA` values and select the first one in each group.

```
library(data.table)

data <- type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE)

setDT(data)[, .N, .(longitude, source)][order(N), .(first = na.omit(source)[1]),longitude]

#   longitude first
#1:      20.5   OSM
#2:      15.2  SIGE
#3:      24.9  SIGE
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[source == "NA", source := NA]
data[, .N, .(longtiude, source)[order(N), .(first = first(source[complete.cases(source)]), longitude]
```